# Controllers for switching from one view to another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

Lets say I have an instance of `ViewA` on window. `ViewA` has a button on it. When the button is pressed, I want to hide `ViewA` and show `ViewB`. What kind of controller(s) would be involved with this? Is there a controller for the view and the window? If so, who handles the event?

Note: This is for OS/X, not iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample project that demonstrates use of NSViewController:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ViewController/Introduction/Intro.html

Perhaps it will help you to search more effectively by giving you the right terms to use.

Comment: Normally I'd ignore link only answers, but in this case I think it's the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it pulls together a lot of concepts in one place. My searches have been almost completely worthless and I dont really have the time to take every tutorial out there.

Comment: This is perfect... even better than the tutorials that walk me through each step. Those are good to actually get the mechanics down but this project is showing me how to set more realistic things up. Thanks for the link!